# Batch file getting syntax error

Tags: c#, batch-file, error-handling

I am trying to write a batch file that checks if your computer name is a certain name, and then if it matches the exe file will run.

```
@echo off

echo adidas shoe cop bot console...
echo by sam
pause

echo checking for computer name...

If %computername%=="DESKTOP-HQPDA76"
   then echo %computername% found
   echo user confirmed
   echo starting file
   pause
   start /B "" "C:\Users\Sam Marriott\Desktop\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot\Package\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot\bin\Debug\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot.exe"
   pause
Else NOT %computername%=="DESKTOP-HQPDA76"
   then echo user access denied
   pause
```

I am getting some error about (something) was not expected here, or syntax error, but I can't really read it because the command prompt closes too quickly. Any help?

Comment: Helps if you read the documentation for the command.  Open up a cmd prompt and type: `if /?`

Comment: for debugging don't run it per double-click. Open a `cmd` window and run it manually from there. So the windows will stay open when an error occurs.

Comment: What did this question have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for the IF statement is wrong. Try this:

```
@echo off

echo adidas shoe cop bot console...
echo by sam
pause

echo checking for computer name...

if "%computername%"=="DESKTOP-HQPDA76" (
    echo %computername% found
    echo user confirmed
    echo starting file
    pause
    start /B "" "C:\Users\Sam Marriott\Desktop\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot\Package\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot\bin\Debug\Adidas Shoe Cop Bot.exe"
    pause
) else (
     echo user access denied
     pause
)
```

Comment: Don't need the extra `IF` comparison.  The else will already execute if the computer name is not equal.